# Ag-Grid :: how to export childgrid inside master grid

Tags: ag-grid

I have Ag-grid with master grid and child grid like this https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/

When i export using     gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel(params);
then it export only master grid content,..child grid content not showing in exported excel..

Please show me example of child grid export inside master grid/.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `gridOptions.api`- which is refer to main grid API, to get child exported you have to use `gridOptionsChild.api` - which could be bounded within the child `gridReady` function.

Answer (score 0):

Won't it just export the child then? What is the best way to merge both grids in proper format like

```
MainGridRow
MainGridRow
DetailGridRow
DetailGridRow
MainGridRow
MainGridRow
DetailGridRow
```

and so on...